Captum TCAV train.py sgd_train_linear_model() Where do the weights come from?
I am using the captum setup
https://captum.ai/api/concept.html
https://captum.ai/tutorials/TCAV_Image
In the Default Classifier the linear classification boils down to the function sgd_train_linear_model(). When I debug the code until sklearn_model.fit(x, y, sample_weight=w, **fit_kwargs) at line 327 the variabe "w" is empty.
But then at line 338:
# Convert weights to pytorch
    classes = (
        torch.IntTensor(sklearn_model.classes_)
        if hasattr(sklearn_model, "classes_")
        else None
    )

It can suddendly derrive the weights from the model. How so? Help me understand.
Debug and read the docs.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
